# Compiling and running a java program - NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, compilation, command-line-interface

Hi guys I have a very frustrating problem:

I have a following diectory structure:

```
.
└── Java Project
    ├── bin
    │   └── edu
    │       └── agh
    │           └── cs
    │               └── jtplab (HelloWorld.class)
    ├── lib
    └── src
        ├── edu
        │   └── agh
        │       └── cs
        │           └── jtplab (HelloWorld.java)
        └── resources
```

In lib directory I have log4j2 external jars. And in helloworld.java there is just some simple system.out.println and log4j2 import statements. The program compiles and runs in Eclipse correctly But When I am compiling my program being in "Java Project" dir using command:

```
javac  -cp `find . -name "*.jar" | tr "\n" ":"`:. -d bin src/edu/agh/cs/jtplab/HelloWorld.java
```

Then it compiles correctly (It doesnt shout about being unable to locate log4j2)

And in order to run the program I then enter "bin" directory

```
cd bin/   
java edu/agh/cs/jtplab/HelloWorld
```

And unfortunately I am getting error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
....
```

I believe that this errors is caused because JVM cant find the proper .jars during runtime execution, but why it cant find it when the javac compiled the program correctly??

When I delete the log4j2 import statements then the program runs w/o problems.

How to compile/run this program correctly to use the log4j2 jars.

Thanks

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError occurs when a .class file for the named class is found, but, upon attempting to "load" the class, for some reason it is not valid.  There are many possible causes, but the most common is having mismatched jar files.

Comment: Maybe you didn't set env variable: JAVA_HOME?